# Android Sticky Immersive mode

Tags: java, android, fullscreen

so I have an activity and I want it full screen, display the title bar and the system buttons (back, minimize...).
I did take a code from developers.android.com and it does go full screen but when I press my screen, the title pops back and so do the buttons come up and I want it to popup only when I slide my finger up/down on the top/bottom of my screen.

My activity looks like:

```
package com.example.nsomething.main;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.nsomething.R;

public class Report extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        setContentView(R.layout.report);

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        Button report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Report.this, Harta.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the code at [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#sticky), you may better to put the code in **onWindowFocusChanged**.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```