# How to make completely transparent status bar?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make so my status bar is transparent, but also without icons on it. I managed to make it so that bar disappeared, but then it left a line that isn't filled with the background. I want to change that so i can actually see the background **without any icons being in the way**.

*Also, I'm testing it on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8T*

Code *(with the result seen on the 1st picture)*

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI()
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = 
                (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Both themes.xml

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.TestingSystemModes" parent="Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here is how it looks with that line:

[image]

I want it to look like in the picture below, **but without that status bar's icons**:

[image]

**EDIT:
I think, it's phone that makes it like that ( in the center there is a camera ) and probably the black line is made to blend in the camera. That's why, whatever i did it didn't disappear. Still, thanks a lot to everyone who tried to help me.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Sticky Immersive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111751/android-sticky-immersive-mode)

Comment: @RyanM this is what i already have, but then it leaves that black line ( as you can see on the first picture )

Comment: Please add the Activity as well as theme applied here.

Comment: @Chandankushwaha added

Comment: Hmm, you're right, your code does do that.  Must be something else, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:**

Phone's can now have a "cut-out" (for notched phones etc. etc.), and when you hide the status bar properly, the phone thinks "ok, I need to make the former status bar just a black cut-out so it doesn't look silly."

**The solution:**

There's actually four things you need to do:

1. Tell Android you don't want status bars in the app (hide them). There is now a correct, backwards compatible way of doing this which I will detail below.
2. Tell Android to draw the app behind the cut-out area.
3. Tell Android that your layout should NOT fit the system window (if you don't do this, it will STILL put your layout within the space where the status bar used to be)
4. Manually adjust the bottom insets, as when you tell Android your layout should not fit the system window (step 3), unfortunately that's going to include the Navigation Bar, so if you don't adjust for this then your layout will be under the nav bar which may be undesirable.

**The Code:**

The below is a neat little extension function that will cover steps 1 and 3... (hide the status bars, set `decorFitsSystemWindows` to false). This allows, in your activity to simply put `window.setInImmersiveMode()`

```
fun Window.setInImmersiveMode() {
    val windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(decorView) ?: return
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(this, false)
}
```

You need to change your themes.xml to tell Android to draw behind these cutouts, with this line (api 27 and above only, hence the tools:targetApi part):

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">shortEdges</item>
```

And finally, there's a slightly more complex bit of code to handle setting up the bottom insets for your layout - again I've made it into an extension function so you can call `view.setupInsets()`:

```
fun View.setupInsets() {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this) { view, windowInsets ->
        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        view.layoutParams = (view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
            bottomMargin = insets.bottom
        }
        WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave up on this project long ago, but when i got the answer, i went ahead to test this and oh god, it really works ! Thanks for detailed explanation and i hope me in the future will use this or people who will have the same problem :D

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties in your theme. Thats all

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: Then it looks like on the 2nd picture, and i don't want these icons to be visible ( 2nd picute was made with this method )

Comment: getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: Check this by adding on Activity below onCreate Method

Comment: It didn't change anything, there is still that black line

Answer (score 0):

you can use below lines to make it transparent or can set fix color       getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ContactUsActivity.this,R.color.white));// set status background white